# IIS 10 WebDAV Windows client gets 403 2 sc-win32-status 5 while Android works

Tags: windows-server-2019, webdav, iis-10

I have Windows Server 2019 with IIS 10 WebDAV share. I access to this share on Windows 11 notebook and Android with CxFileExplorer. There were updates on both notebook and Windows Server 2019. Now Android works with share OK, but Windows client in Explorer and Outlook publisher fails. OPTIONS works, but PROPFIND fails. I tried to login as android from notebook, but still fail. From logs:

```
2023-10-11 13:43:31 165.73.252.146 PROPFIND /Backup/[server]/ - 443 [domain]\android 212.16.10.32 DavClient-okhttp3/0.1.0 - 207 0 0 230
2023-10-11 13:43:44 165.73.252.146 OPTIONS / - 443 - 212.16.10.32 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.22621 - 401 2 5 158
2023-10-11 13:43:44 165.73.252.146 OPTIONS / - 443 [domain]\laptop 212.16.10.32 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.22621 - 200 0 0 161
2023-10-11 13:43:45 165.73.252.146 PROPFIND / - 443 - 212.16.10.32 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.22621 - 401 2 5 158
2023-10-11 13:43:45 165.73.252.146 PROPFIND / - 443 [domain]\laptop 212.16.10.32 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.22621 - 403 2 5 210
```

Please, help. Just a little bit before it worked. I touched nothing, but there were updates. I enabled directory listing, I enabled infinite depth property query according to posts in Internet.